# How can I make the mousewheel scroll an overflow:auto div while it is not in focus?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've made a jQuery-UI menu that shows the description for each choice in a div when the menu item is moused over. I would like to make it so that a user could use the mousewheel to scroll the description div while keeping the menu item highlighted for ease-of-navigation. You can see the code in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/ManOrMonster/Da97r/

```
$(function () {
  $('#menu').menu();
  $('.choice').mouseover(function () {
    var val = $(this).attr('id');
    if (val == 1) {
        desc = "This is the value of choice 1. It is a particularly good choice, unless you are not into 1, in which case this choice is probably not the best. Perhaps 2 or 3 would be a better choice for your tastes?";
    } else if (val == 2) {
        desc = "This is the value of choice 2. While not as interesting a choice as 1 or 3, simply because it is merely middle-of-the-road, it does have several advantages. Firstly, it is twice as many as 1. Secondly, it is not as bloated as 3, by virtue of being 1 less than said choice.";
    } else {
        desc = "This is the value of choice 3. Some people are not satisifed with 1. For others, 2 simply won't do. To please both of these categories of persons of discriminating tastes, 3 was introduced. Like its forerunners, it is exactly 1 more than the one preceding it; however, unlike those who precede it, it is only 1 less than 4, which is regrettably not a choice at all.";
    }
    $("#description").html(desc);
  });
});
```

**UPDATE**

What I've finally ended up with is the following:

```
$('body').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
    if (delta > 0){ // scroll direction is up
        $("#description").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo","top",{scrollInertia:3000});
    } else {
        $("#description").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo","bottom",{scrollInertia:3000});
}
});
```

This makes the scroll go smoothly enough so that the user can control it, even though it will continue to scroll after a single scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this plugin: http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/docs to detect mousewheel and then get the `scrollTop` of the div and manually scroll it.  Might look like this:

```
$('body').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
    var thisTop = $("#description").scrollTop();
    if (delta > 0){ // scroll direction is up
        $("#description").scrollTop(thisTop - delta);
    }
    else {
        $("#description").scrollTop(thisTop + delta);
    }
});
```

**Edit**

Your plugin has a `scrollTo` method that could be used in place of `scrollTop`.  Try replacing this code:

```
$("#description").scrollTop(thisTop - delta);
```

With this:

```
$("#description").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",thisTop - delta);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, adding focus() seems to do nothing. Also, I am using the mousewheel plugin on my site because I'm using custom scrollbars.

Comment: perhaps you can figure a way to use `.scrollTop()` in the mousewheel event to scroll the div?

Comment: yeah that would only give it focus until any other event (like mousewheel up or down) removes the focus.  However, I edited my answer to show how it might look.

Comment: This seems like it should work, but nothing happens. It's definitely firing; I put a console.log in the if statement. However, even if I set the div to manually be at any particular number using scrollTop, that doesn't even work. For instance, `$("#description").html(desc).scrollTop(300);` does nothing.

Comment: Correction: I'm using a plugin called mCustomScrollbar, and the manual scrollTop doesn't work when using that, otherwise it works... `$(".description").html(result).mCustomScrollbar({scrollInertia:200}).scrollTop(300);` doesn't work but without mCustomScrollbar, it does. However, the function you provided doesn't work whether I'm using the plugin or not.

Comment: Well, you can at least see the logic behind it and hopefully find a right answer. I have not used either plugin before. I will check out mCustomScrollbar

Comment: I did find "scrollTo" and have been messing around with it but I couldn't figure out how to make the value so that it will scroll smoothly. `thisTop-delta` doesn't work because `thisTop` always remains 0 for some reason. You can see my final solution above. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: yeah I found that problem in the js file as it overrides scrollTop, I don't know how to fix it though hah.